# JavaPoet - ParameterizedTypeName with nested ParameterizedTypeName

Tags: java, javapoet

How can I create following:

```
HashMap<String, Pair<Boolean, Object>> mHashMap = new HashMap();
```

I have following:

```
ParameterizedTypeName subType = ParameterizedTypeName.get(Pair.class, Boolean.class, Object.class);
ParameterizedTypeName mainType = ParameterizedTypeName.get(HashMap.class, String.class, Pair.class);
 builder.addField(
            FieldSpec.builder(mainType, "mHashMap", Modifier.PRIVATE, Modifier.FINAL)
                    .initializer("new HashMap<>()")
                    .build()
    );
```

How can I now combine the `subType` with the `mainType` to get the correct `mainType`?

I need something like following:

```
ParameterizedTypeName mainType = ParameterizedTypeName.get(HashMap.class, String.class, subType);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ParameterizedTypeName subType = ParameterizedTypeName.get(Pair.class, 
                                                          Boolean.class,
                                                          Object.class);
ClassName string = ClassName.get("java.lang", 
                                 "String");
ClassName hashMap = ClassName.get("java.util", 
                                  "HashMap");
ParameterizedTypeName mainType = ParameterizedTypeName.get(hashMap, 
                                                           string,
                                                           subType);

FieldSpec.builder(mainType, 
                  "mHashMap",
                  Modifier.PRIVATE,
                  Modifier.FINAL)
         .initializer("new HashMap<>()")
         .build();
```

The code above should generate:

```
private final HashMap<String, Pair<Boolean, Object>> mHashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `ClassName.get("java.lang", "String")` can be replaced with `ClassName.get(String.class)` but thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for